# How to share My Sites with another user using FileZilla Site Manager

Tags: filezilla

How do I share My Sites with another user using FileZilla Site Manager? Can I export My Sites somehow and send it? I am looking for a way not to manually copy an entire list of Sites in FileZilla. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can export your sites and send it to someone.

1. Click on 'File' in the menu bar.
2. Click on 'Export'
3. Select Export Site Manager entries

A save dialog should popup and you can save the XML file somwhere on your desktop and send that to the person you want to share it with.

The other person should then import that file.

1. Click on 'File' in the menu bar.
2. Click on 'Import'
3. Open the XML file

Comment: @ftpfordays  So consider [accepting the answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it helped you.